# Event listening notifying another event

Tags: c#, events

I am not sure if this is the correct title, but I will explain.
I have two classes, `Test` and `Boo`, written by myself. A third class called `Manager` is also there. I would like to initiate a `Manager` object and then listen for changes in a method in class `Test`.

```
public class Test
{
    Manager manager;
    public event EventHandler NotifyMe;

    public Test()
    {
        manager = new Manager();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        manager.ChangedState += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.State);
            NotifyMe(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have the class `Boo` with a method `foo()` when I want to listen my `NotifyMe` event and eventually get if the `manager` object has fired up `ChangedState`.

```
public class Boo
{
    public void foo()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.start();

        test.NotifyMe += (sender, e) =>
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Manager has changed the state");
        }   
    }
}
```

This works only the first time, when I'm executing the `start()` and my idea is to listen on the `manager.ChangedState` through `test.NotifyMe` all the time. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Do you need to wire up your event handler (test.NotifyMe) before calling start?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `test` is a local variable.  As soon as `foo` exits, the object to which it refers is eligible for garbage collection; once that object has been garbage collected, it will no longer write to the console.  Try this:

```
public class Boo
{
    private readonly Test _test = new Test();

    public void foo()
    {
        _test.start();

        _test.NotifyMe += (sender, e) =>
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Manager has changed the state");
        }   
    }
}
```